# Proget Bower feed throws error

Tags: bower, proget

While using a P{roget Bower feed, we are getting the following error. I don't seem to find solution anywhere on the internet. 
EINVRES Response of request to http://*****/feeds/bower/Bower/packages/packages/bootstrap is not a valid json

Here is my .bowerrc

```
{
"proxy":"http://****:3500",
"https-proxy":"http://****:3500",
"http-proxy":"http://****:3500",
"strict-ssl": false,    
"registry": {
"search": [
"http://*****/feeds/bower/Bower",
"https://registry.bower.io"
]
}
}
```

I will appreciate any help to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When running Bower, use the feed endpoint URL, e.g.:

```
http://proget/bower/{bowerFeedName}/...
```

instead of the Feed Overview URL, e.g.:

```
http://proget/feeds/{bowerFeedName}/
```

The latter is meant for browsing via the web UI.